# Closing a form from a FlowPanel image

Tags: c#, winforms, flowpanel

When you click on an image in my flowView, a new window appears. On this appearing I want the Form containing the FlowView to be closed.

I've found a way to do it however, it is very messy and surely there's a better way? My code which works but seems bad is below.

```
this.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Dispose();
```

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `FindForm()` can help.

Comment: Awesome thanks that works